# Эффект нажатия на кнопку и округление кнопки

Tags: android, button, background, android-button

Такой вопрос : создал `XML файл`, в котором реализуется "эффект нажатия на кнопку" и задаю в `background` кнопки данный файл.Затем я создал XML файл, чтобы округлить кнопку. И теперь,когда мне надо задать округление кнопки в `background`, то я уже не могу, т.к. там прописан файл"эффекта нажатия на кнопку". Как быть? 
Пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@color/backgorund_splash"/>
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />
    </selector>
```

Comment: Добавьте округление в первый файл

Comment: @АндроидАндроид добавил пример кода. Что именно прописать и куда ?

Comment: щас ответом примерно накидаю

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть примерно так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
           <shape>
           <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
           <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
           </shape>
        </item>
        ..... 
 </selector>
```

Comment: пишу solid, пишу corners - не отображаются в тегах

Comment: @Programmer поправил